# amazon in parallel with prebid using simplerGPT and refresh

Tags: google-dfp, prebid.js

I'm trying to get amazon working in parallel with prebid uiing amazons simplerGPT and refresh, having no luck getting it going, would anyone have got it going and can help me?

Thansk

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code sample on the APS documentation ([here](https://ams.amazon.com/webpublisher/uam/docs/get-started/parallel-integration-alongside-prebid.html))

```
<script>
/** Executes a parallel auction with prebid **/
function executeParallelAuctionAlongsidePrebid() {

    var FAILSAFE_TIMEOUT = 2000;
    var requestManager = {
        adserverRequestSent: false,
        aps: false,
        prebid: false
    };

    // when both APS and Prebid have returned, initiate ad request
    function biddersBack() {
        if (requestManager.aps && requestManager.prebid) {
            sendAdserverRequest();
        } 
        return;
    }

    // sends adserver request
    function sendAdserverRequest() {
        if (requestManager.adserverRequestSent === true) {
            return;
        }
        requestManager.adserverRequestSent = true;
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.pubads().refresh();
        });
    }

    // sends bid request to APS and Prebid
    function requestHeaderBids() {

        // APS request
        apstag.fetchBids({
                slots: [{
                    slotID: 'your-gpt-div-id',
                    slotName: '12345/yourAdUnit',
                    sizes: [[300, 250], [300, 600]]
                }]
            },function(bids) {
                googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                    apstag.setDisplayBids();
                    requestManager.aps = true; // signals that APS request has completed
                    biddersBack(); // checks whether both APS and Prebid have returned
                });
            }
        );

        // put prebid request here
        pbjs.que.push(function() {
            pbjs.requestBids({
                bidsBackHandler: function() {
                    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                        pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync();
                        requestManager.prebid = true; // signals that Prebid request has completed
                        biddersBack(); // checks whether both APS and Prebid have returned
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // initiate bid request
    requestHeaderBids();

    // set failsafe timeout
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        sendAdserverRequest();
    }, FAILSAFE_TIMEOUT);
};
</script>
```